# Problems while building QGIS 2.15.0 on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cmake, qgis

I am following the instructions provided with the INSTALL file in QGIS-master

The following variable has been set to:

```
PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;C:\OSGeo4W\bin\C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\sip\PyQt4\QtXml;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;c:\cygwin;

PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27

PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27
```

Successfully configured and generated through cmake-gui (3.0.2)

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for building Release (Win32) on Win8.1 64 bit

The output is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: version, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: ui, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: qgis_core, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
4 Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/src/core/CMakeLists.txt
4 CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\src\core\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
4 Generating C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/src/core/qgscontexthelp_texts.cpp
5>------ Build started: Project: pyqtcompat, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
4 Traceback (most recent call last):
4   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 563, in <module>
4     main()
4   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 545, in main
4     known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
4   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
4     user_site = getusersitepackages()
4   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
4     user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
4   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 242, in getuserbase
4     from sysconfig import get_config_var
4 ImportError: No module named sysconfig
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
6>------ Build started: Project: qgis_gui, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: python_module_qgis__core, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
7 Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/CMakeLists.txt
7 CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
7 Generating core/sip_corepart0.cpp, core/sip_corepart1.cpp, core/sip_corepart2.cpp, core/sip_corepart3.cpp
7 
7>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
8>------ Build started: Project: pycore, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
6>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\core\RelWithDebInfo\qgis_core.lib'
9>------ Build started: Project: python_module_qgis__gui, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
9 Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/CMakeLists.txt
9 CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
9 Generating gui/sip_guipart0.cpp, gui/sip_guipart1.cpp, gui/sip_guipart2.cpp, gui/sip_guipart3.cpp
9 
10>------ Build started: Project: zzz-processing-56-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
.........
44>------ Build started: Project: zzz-processing-22-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
9>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
45>------ Build started: Project: pygui, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
46>------ Build started: Project: zzz-processing-21-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
.........
55>------ Build started: Project: zzz-db_manager-7-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
54 Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/plugins/db_manager/db_plugins/postgis/plugins/versioning/CMakeLists.txt
54 CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugins\versioning\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
54 Generating ui_DlgVersioning.py
54 Traceback (most recent call last):
54   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 563, in <module>
54     main()
54   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 545, in main
54     known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
54   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
54     user_site = getusersitepackages()
54   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
54     user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
54   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 242, in getuserbase
54     from sysconfig import get_config_var
54 ImportError: No module named sysconfig
54>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
56>------ Build started: Project: zzz-db_manager-6-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
.........
60>------ Build started: Project: zzz-db_manager-15-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
59 Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/plugins/db_manager/CMakeLists.txt
59 CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\plugins\db_manager\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
59 Generating ui_DlgAddGeometryColumn.py
59 Traceback (most recent call last):
59   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 563, in <module>
59     main()
59   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 545, in main
59     known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
59   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
59     user_site = getusersitepackages()
59   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
59     user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
59   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 242, in getuserbase
59     from sysconfig import get_config_var
59 ImportError: No module named sysconfig
59>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
61>------ Build started: Project: zzz-db_manager-14-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
.........
78>------ Build started: Project: zzz-GdalTools-1-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
77 Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/plugins/GdalTools/tools/CMakeLists.txt
77 CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\plugins\GdalTools\tools\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
77 Generating ui_dialogAbout.py
77 Traceback (most recent call last):
77   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 563, in <module>
77     main()
77   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 545, in main
77     known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
77   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
77     user_site = getusersitepackages()
77   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
77     user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
77   File "\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib/site.py", line 242, in getuserbase
77     from sysconfig import get_config_var
77 ImportError: No module named sysconfig
77>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
...
========== Build: 107 succeeded, 193 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The Python errors were resolved by adding python/lib to %PATH%
Now I am getting the following errors

```
67>------ Build started: Project: zzz-processing-61-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
4>spatialite.lib(alloc_cache.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlInitParser referenced in function _spatialite_initialize
4>spatialite.lib(alloc_cache.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlCleanupParser referenced in function _spatialite_shutdown
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlFreeDoc referenced in function _splite_free_xml_schema_cache_item
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlFreeDoc
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSchemaFree referenced in function _splite_free_xml_schema_cache_item
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt referenced in function _splite_free_xml_schema_cache_item
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlDocGetRootElement referenced in function _sniff_payload
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlDocGetRootElement
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _crc32 referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_relations.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _crc32
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _compress referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _compressBound referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSchemaFreeValidCtxt referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSchemaValidateDoc referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlReadMemory referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlReadMemory
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSchemaParse referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlReadFile referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSetGenericErrorFunc referenced in function _gaiaXmlToBlob
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlSetGenericErrorFunc
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uncompress referenced in function _gaiaXmlTextFromBlob
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlDocDumpFormatMemory referenced in function _gaiaXmlLoad
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathFreeObject referenced in function _gaiaXmlGetInternalSchemaURI
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathFreeObject
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathFreeContext referenced in function _gaiaXmlGetInternalSchemaURI
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathFreeContext
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlFreeNode referenced in function _setIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlReplaceNode referenced in function _setIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlAddChild referenced in function _setIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewText referenced in function _setIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewNode referenced in function _setIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__xmlFree referenced in function _gaiaXmlBlobSetFileId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSetNs referenced in function _addIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewNs referenced in function _addIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlAddPrevSibling referenced in function _addIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlAddNextSibling referenced in function _addIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSearchNs referenced in function _addIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(gg_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlSearchNsByHref referenced in function _addIsoId
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathFreeCompExpr referenced in function _gaiaIsValidXPathExpression
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathCompile referenced in function _gaiaIsValidXPathExpression
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathEvalExpression referenced in function _vxpath_eval_expr
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathRegisterNs referenced in function _vxpath_eval_expr
4>spatialite.lib(virtualxpath.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xmlXPathNewContext referenced in function _vxpath_eval_expr
4>spatialite.lib(virtualXL.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _freexl_get_cell_value referenced in function _vXL_create
4>spatialite.lib(virtualXL.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _freexl_worksheet_dimensions referenced in function _vXL_create
4>spatialite.lib(virtualXL.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _freexl_select_active_worksheet referenced in function _vXL_create
4>spatialite.lib(virtualXL.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _freexl_get_info referenced in function _vXL_create
4>spatialite.lib(virtualXL.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _freexl_close referenced in function _vXL_create
4>spatialite.lib(virtualXL.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _freexl_open referenced in function _vXL_create
4>spatialite.lib(gg_utf8.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _locale_charset referenced in function _gaiaGetLocaleCharset
4>spatialite.lib(gg_utf8.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libiconv_close referenced in function _gaiaConvertCharset
4>spatialite.lib(gg_shape.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _libiconv_close
4>spatialite.lib(gg_utf8.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libiconv referenced in function _gaiaConvertCharset
4>spatialite.lib(gg_shape.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _libiconv
4>spatialite.lib(gg_utf8.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libiconv_open referenced in function _gaiaConvertCharset
4>spatialite.lib(gg_shape.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _libiconv_open
4>C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\output\bin\RelWithDebInfo\qgis_core.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 48 unresolved externals
68>------ Build started: Project: qgis_gui, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
69>------ Build started: Project: python_module_qgis__core, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
69>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/CMakeLists.txt
69>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
69>  Generating core/sip_corepart0.cpp, core/sip_corepart1.cpp, core/sip_corepart2.cpp, core/sip_corepart3.cpp
69>  
69>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
70>------ Build started: Project: pycore, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
```

I also retried installing spatialite from OSGEO4W a couple of times with the same result...

---update---

```
<omitted>
47>------ Build started: Project: python_module_qgis__core, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
47>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/CMakeLists.txt
47>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
47>  Generating core/sip_corepart0.cpp, core/sip_corepart1.cpp, core/sip_corepart2.cpp, core/sip_corepart3.cpp
47>  
47>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
<omitted>
79>------ Build started: Project: python_module_qgis__gui, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
79>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/python/CMakeLists.txt
79>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\python\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
79>  Generating gui/sip_guipart0.cpp, gui/sip_guipart1.cpp, gui/sip_guipart2.cpp, gui/sip_guipart3.cpp
79>  
79>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
<omitted>
103>------ Build started: Project: synccrsdb, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
103>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master/src/crssync/CMakeLists.txt
103>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\Abdul\Downloads\QGIS\QGIS-master-build\src\crssync\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
104>------ Build started: Project: qgisgrass7, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
104>     Creating library C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master-build/src/providers/grass/7/RelWithDebInfo/qgisgrass7.lib and object C:/Users/Abdul/Downloads/QGIS/QGIS-master-build/src/providers/grass/7/RelWithDebInfo/qgisgrass7.exp
103>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 255.
<omitted>
108>------ Build started: Project: qgis, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo Win32 ------
107>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
```

Comment: I'm not using qgis, but isn't this error message `ImportError: No module named sysconfig` unclear? Can you try example from here https://docs.python.org/2/library/sysconfig.html and see how it works?

Comment: thanks @sergei
Now I am getting the errors as in the updated post...

Comment: Now you should provide libxml2 and libiconv for linker.

Comment: Where in cmake list or visual studio 2010 am I supposed to put those???

libxml2.obj and iconv.obj are existent in c:\osgeo4w\lib

iconv.h and libxml folder is also existing in c:\osgeo4w\include

iconv.dll and libxml2.dll are available in c:\osgeo4w\bin

Comment: Resolved most of the linker errors by specifying
    Compiled spatialite and specified spatialite.lib and spatialite_i.lib as additional dependencies in Project Properties -> Custom Build Tool.